# Copying Lead field type==ID to Oppo lookup field (also type==ID) during lead conversion

Tags: visual-workflow, process-builder

I built an easy process in Process Builder where I can bring over the LeadOwnerId to a new field on the Opportunity when it's converted called LeadOwnerId__c.  However, I'm running into the Too Many SOQL queries error at different times during the day.

Is there something I can do in Flow?  Would I have PB call a flow after a lead has been converted?

I can write a trigger but I would like to see if I can accomplish this via point and click.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create formula field of type text in lead object to copy owner. Then in lead field mapping setting , map this new field to opportunity where you want to copy lead ownerID.

Unfortunately PB is not bulkified and it will also use one query to update record.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear.  I am trying to copy the LeadOwnerId to another ID field on the opportunity called LeadOwnerid__c.  Unfortunately this isn't possible out of the box